# Why simple cells loads before custom cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have made customCell for my UITableView. I am downloading data from server and showing on CustomCells.

The method of manipulating data is

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCellReuseID";

LeaderBoardCell *cell = [leaderBoardTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[LeaderBoardCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

GetScoreBoard *ob = [leaderBoardArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[[cell title] setText:ob.fullname];
[[cell discription] setText:ob.points];

return cell;


}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
    }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [leaderBoardArray count];

 }
```

The CustomCell "LeaderBoardCell" is loading later, but before this I see simple cells which are default in UITableView.

Is is possible to load only CustomCell in TableVeiw?

Comment: Can you post your `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` implementation?

Comment: added methods which you are required @Chris McKnight

Comment: Do you have your cell's custom class set in the storyboard/xib as `LeaderBoardCell`?

Comment: Yes, it loads but a bit later, not as early as UITableView shows its cell.

Comment: I ask about the storyboard/xib because it sounds like the storyboard/xib is loading first. Then your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` runs and sets it to the `LeaderBoardCell.` Set a few breakpoints in cellForRowAtIndexPath and set a breakpoint at the return statement of `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView`. Step over the code and pay attention to what you see on the screen.

Comment: How do you know that the cells loaded first are regular tableview cells and not actually your custom cells?